# Changes to sqlite in ios 7/XCode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, ios7

I am working on an app that I originally built to support iOS 5.1/6.0/6.1. I recently upgraded to XCODE 5 and the sqlite 'select' queries now all return null although the correct database is there, and have been connected to and the tables recognized. The strange part is that the app is working flawlessly on all the simulators 5.1-7.0 but not on an actual device. I only have 5.1 device available to test.

I reinstalled XCode 4 and the app is compiling and running as expected on iOS 5.1 device. Are there any changes that to the SQLITE or the compiler or some other component in XCode 5 that would give this problem?

Code could be provided if that would assist in helping troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Code would probably help. Does your code log the `sqlite3_errmsg` if the result of any call is not `SQLITE_OK` (or `SQLITE_DONE`/`SQLITE_ROW` in the case of `sqlite3_step`)? Usually, unexplained SQLite errors are illuminated by looking at return codes and, on error, `sqlite3_errmsg`. I know of no material changes in SQLite in iOS 7. Many of us are using SQLite in iOS 7 without incident.

Comment: I suspect that the database is not really there, having gotten lost in the file system, or you're attempting to use a DB in the bundle.

Comment: Hotlicks - I have used 'iFile' to examine the app's files and can confirm that the Database is there. Its in the Documents folder as well as the .app bundle. I have also examined the DB and can confirm that the data and tables are in the database. The db is successfully being connected to, its just that the select queries are returning null.

Comment: @Rob - I aren't deploying to iOS 7. I'm deploying to 5.1 in both cases. The only difference is the XCode. I works when it compiled with XCode 4 but doesn't when compiled with XCode 5, the select queries return null, although the db is there and it is connected to. I'll try using more sqlite3_errmsg to try to identify the fault and post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the sqlite's file size, i have the same problem but i resolved copying the pre populated .sqlite to the Documents directory via Finder at
/Users//Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator//Applications//Documents. But first let core data create the wrong sqlite before then replace the file created for the correct one.

Seems like Xcode doesn't copy the pre populated sqlite file to the main bundle instead it create a new one based on the core data model.